# Manner: a way in which a thing is done or happens

Tags: word-meaning

Does ‘manner’ only mean quality, not a thing?

I mean, does yellowness or happiness can be a way, but does a car or cake cannot be a way?

Comment: **Happily** can be the way in which something is done - happiness  can't.

Comment: But happily is an adverb

Comment: happy is an adjective; happiness is a feeling (not a way) of being happy; happily is an adverb which means in a happy way/manner

Comment: I know _happily_ is an adverb - an adverb describes the _way_ (or _manner_) in which something is done.

Comment: Are you asking for the definition of "manner"?  "The way in which something is done".  "yellow" can't be a manner.  You can't do something in a yellow way.  Nor in a car way, nor in a cake way.  But you can do something in happy way.

Comment: *Car* is a noun. It cannot describe a verb. Read it aloud. How do you swim? Car. See - it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is especially relevant to death certificates or forensic pathologists' findings.

Thus
the CAUSE of death was a gunshot wound to the head.
The **Manner** of Death could be Murder, Suicide, or Misadventure.

**Manner would have to be an adverb applying to the action**, thus

(doing/saying something) in an un/willing manner

(doing/saying  something) in an un/cooperative  manner

(doing something) in an in/competent  manner

(doing/saying  something) in a cheerful/surly/meticulous/careless manner